# What does "stocktaking analysis" means in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

"Without GEF support, Iran will not be able to execute the priority actions identified in its stocktaking
analysis, capacity enhancement and consolidation of institutions will be slow or may not occur"

Comment: just glance in a business dictionary for this sort of thing

Comment: You don't given any context for this query, which basically forces people to guess what might be meant if they try to answer. Also, the comma after 'analysis' should be replaced by a full stop/period to prevent a run-on sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Taking stock of a situation is business and strategy allegory to figuring out your current capacities and capabilities.

It is an allegory derived from [stock-taking of inventory,the physical verification of the quantities and condition of items held](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock-taking).

Examples of stock-taking analysis, that might be familiar to some people:
Luke 14:28-31:

> For which one of you, when he wants to build a tower, does not first sit down and calculate the cost to see if he has enough to complete it? Otherwise, when he has laid a foundation and is not able to finish, all who observe it begin to ridicule him.
>   ....
>   Or what king, when he sets out to meet another king in battle, will not first sit down and consider whether he is strong enough with ten thousand men to encounter the one coming against him with twenty thousand?

In the case of Iran, the statement asserts that Iran would need to exploit the GEF's repertoire of expertise, lessons learnt, and experiences accumulated among the collection of its 183 member countries, in order to proceed effectively, or even at all, in its efforts towards capacity enhancement and consolidation of institutions.